# How to omit the last variable in an arglist using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

When calling a function which has 3 arguments (a, b & c respectively) where the last two are optional. Excel seems to force me to always supply the latest variable. When not supplying argument **c** , I recieve a *Compile Error /  Syntax Error.*
But I don't understand why?
How to omit the last variable from an argument list?

**Function**

```
Function passing_variables(a, Optional b = 1, Optional c = 1)
    passing_variables = a * b * c
End Function
```

**Does not work**

```
Sub main_procedure
    Cells(17, 2) = passing_variables(2, 4 , )
End Sub
```

**Works**

```
Sub main_procedure
    Cells(17, 2) = passing_variables(2, ,4)
End Sub
```

Possible workaround is to provide named variables as stated by [Microsoft Language reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments)

Comment: The first one, you don't need the last comma

Comment: You're right. You can't do that like that. You instead just use `Cells(17, 2) = passing_variables(2, 4)`

Comment: Thanks, I am used to Python where this was the case I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just omit it. For example:

```
Sub Test()
    Debug.Print MyFunction(Var1:=2, Var2:=4)
    Debug.Print MyFunction(Var1:=2, Var2:=4, Inverse:=True)
End Sub

Function MyFunction(Var1 as Long, Var2 as Long, Optional Inverse as Boolean = False)
    MyFunction = Var1 * Var2
    If Inverse Then MyFunction = MyFunction * -1
End Function
```

In the first call, "Inverse" is omitted.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe just a typo

```
Sub main_procedure
    Cells(17, 2) = passing_variables(2, 4)
End Sub
```

Comment: At least not on purpose :D, I am used to Python where this is not the case.